# Maximum Number of Glassfish Nodes?

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, glassfish

My company has begun deploying Glassfish as our app server of choice. (For anyone who's curious, we love it!) We have multiple products, so we've taken to setting up one cluster per product. Each node is a rather beefy box, so each node is shared across multiple clusters.

As I've been working to grow our deployments, I've begun wondering if there is a limit to the number of nodes that Glassfish will handle. My understanding is that a given cluster can only replicate up to 5 nodes, but I have not found a limit on the number of nodes managed by a single DAS (Domain Admin Server).

Does anyone know if such a limit exists? While it would be rather neat if we could manage dozens of clusters across dozens of boxes through a single user interface, I'd rather start planning for additional DAS instances now if they should become necessary.

I've checked the Glassfish docs and asked Google half-dozen different ways, so I *think* there's no limit. But I'd like to get some sort of confirmation on that.

Thanks in advance, everyone!

(P.S. Everyone should try Glassfish. If you're still using Tomcat, you don't know what you're missing!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, thank you for choosing GlassFish!

Here are the formal limits:

- No hard (fixed) limit to the number of nodes in a cluster.
- For a highly available cluster (session replication enabled), 10 nodes are what we test and formally support.
- For a non-highly-available cluster, we only test 10, but you can go beyond that.
- Related, we formally support 100 instances managed by a single DAS (some scenarios may reduce that).  This is not a hard (fixed) limit.  You can potentially go way beyond that, but from a Quality Assurance perpsective we test 100.  Commercial customers will be limited to 100 instances managed by a single DAS.

Hope this helps!

John Clingan
GlassFish Server Product Management.

Comment: I should mention that "commercial customers will be limited to 100 instances" is not a product limitation of Oracle GlassFish Server. Support will simply tell you to reduce the number instances to 100 or less.

Comment: Good to know! I don't think we'll be hitting more than 100 nodes in a single data center anytime soon, and I doubt we'd use the same DAS across data centers. So we should be good with those limits. Thanks again for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

At Java One (2011) this exact question was brought up in the Glassfish meetings. I'm sure you could find the video online. Anyway, the issue at hand was the limitation of the Admin Console rather than the container itself. Version 2 seemed to have issues as the node account grew to about 50. In version 3 the limit is supposedly much higher.

ESPN uses a very large cluster to run March Madness. They ran in to the limit a long time ago and just worked around it so it's not a show stopper.

[ESPN Success Story - GlassFish Community Event at JavaOne 2011](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LkJmsaXhq4)